# outlook store events never trigger

Tags: vb.net, event-handling, outlook

When I listen for the Item_add events of each store default folders, they never trigger. How could this be?

```
'doesnt work: 
   For Each st As Outlook.Store In Application.Session.Stores
        AddHandler st.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail)
       .Items.ItemAdd, AddressOf sentmail
        AddHandler st.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail) _
       .Items.ItemAdd, Function() MsgBox(55)
    Next


'works
AddHandler Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail) _
.Items.ItemAdd, AddressOf sentmail
```

Answer (score 0):

The object that fires the events (Items in your case) must be alive to fire events.
Store Items object in a global (class) member, then set up event handlers on that variable.